# Push notification by Twilio and react-native-firebase FCM

Tags: firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, twilio, react-native-firebase

I'm working in the chatapp using Twilio SDK  with React Native.

Now I need the push-notification features. I have set up everything with Twilio & Firebase.

But Twilio push notification does not work.

When app is in **foreground** or **background** (not quit and inactive), I can receive the the data message (without `notification` field) from Twilio.

But when the app is **quit**, there's no message back.

```
messaging().setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
  console.log(': remoteMessage', remoteMessage);
  // FIXME: isn't fired when app is terminated,  fired when you send a notification from Firebase Console
});
```

I checked again if there is any issue from firebase by sending a notification from Firebase Console, the app receive that notification.

So I guess there is something related to Twilio.

Or the event is not called for data-message (message without notification), because Twilio sends back data message.

If that, is there a way to make this work?

Comment: Did you find any solution? How did you implement this?